# Html com load() do jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Estou a tentar usar esta função do Jquery mas não esta a funcionar correctamente pois nao me mostra nada.

```
<script>
$("#minha_div").load("Noticias.html");
</script>

 <div id="minha_div" width="550" height="400"  style="position: absolute; left: 1%; top: 39%;"></div>
```

Na consola aparece:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load. (Caminho do ficheiro)  Cross origin
>   requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: A própria mensagem de erro já diz: você deve adicionar o protocolo, caminho completo, por exemplo: `"http://seusite.com/Noticias.html"`

Comment: Correcto, Mas por exemplo agora estou a testar apenas no computador uma pagina offline. Existe forma de conseguir ver a pagina?

Comment: Direto do sistema de arquivos, sem servidor, não sei se funciona com a função `load()`. Realmente não sei te dizer:(

Comment: Aquela div depois consigo mudar o tamanho para ficar parecido com um iframe?

Comment: colocando essa div primeiro e esse script depois não seria o correto?

Comment: Carregar arquivos vis script do computador local não é permitido por questões de segurança. Imagina o que alguém poderia ler lhe passando um simples HTML!

Answer (score 1):

Utilize jQuey Ajax:

```
$.ajax({ 
     url: "Noticias.html", dataType: "html" 
}).done(function( responseHtml ) {
     $("#minha_div").html(responseHtml);
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ksodxzwp/ 

Assim?

Comment: @ChrisAdler no jsfiddle não vai funcionar, teste na sua máquina onde você tem o script, substitua o código que lá está pelo que postei acima, lembrando que o ficheiro "Noticias.html" tem que estar na mesma pasta onde o script é executado.

Comment: Já testei e não está a funcionar. Usei o Script dentro e fora do Head e não dá

Comment: @ChrisAdler algum erro? Veja com o inspector do browser se existe algum erro no javascript.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/TESTE/Noticia.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource. Poderá ser disto? <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

Comment: Consegui mostrar utilizando o Http:// . Mas agora a pagina aparece com o tamanho original. existe forma de controlar isso?

Comment: @ChrisAdler css.